# How to organise integration specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

With rspec, it's quite clear how you should organise your unit specs. The directory structure inside `spec` is very similar to that found in the `app` directory, so model specs go in the `model` directory, controller specs go in the `controller` directory and so on.

But it's not so clear with integration testing. I have just one file pertaining to integration testing: `spec/features/integration.rb`

Is the idea to create one elaborate spec that tests every faculty of your application? Something like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Everything", js: true do
    before do
            @user_0 = FactoryGirl.build(:user_0)
            @user_1 = FactoryGirl.build(:user_1)
            @user_2 = FactoryGirl.build(:user_2)
            @user_3 = FactoryGirl.build(:user_3)
    end


    it "can create a user" do


            visit root_path
            click_link 'Sign In'

            ap @user_0

            fill_in('Email', with: @user_0.email)
            fill_in('Password', with: @user_0.password)
            click_button 'Sign in'
            visit('/user_friendships')       
        end

        it "can create a user" do
        end

        it "can create a user" do
        end

        it "can create a user" do
        end    

        it "GET /root_path" do
            visit root_path
            page.should have_content("All of our statuses")
            click_link "Post a New Status"
            page.should have_content("New status")
            fill_in "status_content", with: "Oh my god I am going insaaaaaaaaane!!!"
            click_button "Create Status"
            page.should have_content("Status was successfully created.")
            click_link "Statuses"
            page.should have_content("All of our statuses")                       
            page.should have_content("Jimmy balooney")
            page.should have_content("Oh my god I am going insaaaaaaaaane!!! ")
        end
end
```

But a lot longer?

Should I use more than one file? How should I use the describe blocks? I'm only using one at the moment and that doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: No, it's not meant to go into one file.

Bigger projects split their acceptance test-suite into files based on feature sets. If you have a lot of tests, they are often split up into different directories. The way that you organize those tests is up to you. I have seen a lot of different approaches here. I tend to group spec with similar requirements on database setup, aka test-data.

If you want to have great guide for your rspec tests, go and have a look at this site: http://betterspecs.org/

Comment: Okay, cool, and are describe blocks used like contexts are used in a unit spec?

Comment: A common approach for naming and organising is using a schema like `actor_does_what_spec.rb`. For instance, `user_signs_in_spec.rb` or `user_comments_article_spec.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually desirable to split integration tests per page or flow in your application.

For example, you could try:

```rb
# spec/users/sign_in_spec.rb
RSpec.describe 'Users Sign In', js: true do
  let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user_0) }

  it "can sign in" do
    visit root_path
    click_link 'Sign In'
    fill_in('Email', with: user.email)
    fill_in('Password', with: user.password)
    click_button 'Sign in'
    page.should have_content('Signed In')
  end
end
```

```rb
# spec/statuses/manage_status.rb
RSpec.describe 'Statuses', js: true do
  it "should be able to post a status" do
    visit root_path
    page.should have_content("All of our statuses")

    click_link "Post a New Status"
    fill_in "status_content", with: "Everything is Alright"
    click_button "Create Status"
    page.should have_content("Status was successfully created.")

    click_link "Statuses"
    page.should have_content("All of our statuses")                       
    page.should have_content("Everything is Alright ")
  end
end
```

If you are looking for a way to organize your specs, you could use [**Capybara Test Helpers**](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/) to encapsulate the code and make the tests more readable. For example:

```rb
# spec/users/sign_in_spec.rb
RSpec.describe 'Users Sign In', js: true, test_helpers: [:login] do
  let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user_0) }

  it "can sign in" do
    visit root_path
    login.enter_credentials(email: user.email, password: user.password)
    current_page.should.have_content('Signed In')
  end
end
```

```rb
# spec/statuses/manage_status.rb
RSpec.describe 'Statuses', js: true, test_helpers: [:statuses] do
  it "should be able to post a status" do
    visit root_path
    current_page.should.have_content('All of our statuses')
    
    statuses.post('Everything is Alright')
    statuses.should_now.have_status('Everything is Alright')
  end
end
```